# html5 access of a MP3 file's ByteArray

Tags: audio, mp3, media-player, arrays, html5-audio

I would like to build a gapless audio player in html5. The end of the currently playing song should overlap the following one so that there is no pause between them. Conventional gapless players in html5 are not reliable:

Some say : Gapless playback cannot be reliably implemented using HTML5 Audio. There is always going to be an inherent pause between songs. The only way I could simulate gapless playback is by using two HTML5 audio objects, but I would never be able to perfect the timing between the two objects on all devices. So sometimes the songs would play with no gap, sometimes there would be a gap, and sometimes the audio from two consecutive songs would overlap.
source: http://forums.precentral.net/webos-homebrew-apps/261502-music-player-remix-2-0-homebrew-edition-62.html

I believe I can work-around this problem if html5 can access a MP3 file's ByteArray and play "data generated sound". Do you know if html5 is capable to do that?

Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at this point HTML doesn't provide any means for accessing raw audio data in the specification. Some browsers (e.g. Firefox, Chrome) provide audio APIs that can accomplish this. But obviously it's not cross browser compliant. This would leave you writing implementations for various browsers and no support for IE.